# Почему при цикле insertBefore добавляет все три элементы в одно место

Tags: javascript

Есть 3 блока с шириной 8 колонок (класс `news`) и 3 блока с шириной 4 колонок (класс `posts`).

Нужно чтобы при ширине меньше `992` пикселей каждая колонка класса `posts` выровнились **ПОСЛЕ** каждой колонки `news`

А тут выровняется все три элемента в одном месте **после второй колонки** блока `news`

Почему так происходит я вообще не понимаю.

Помогите пожалуйста решить эту проблему

[**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/DuudeXX8/pen/pVXLvb) ссылка

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    let w = window.innerWidth; // ширина окна
    let lastPosts = document.querySelectorAll(".last_posts"); //все колонки внутри блока posts
    let newsInfo = document.querySelectorAll(".news_info");
  //  все колонки внутри блока news
    let news = document.querySelector(".news"); //блок news

    if(w <= 992){ //если ширина меньше 992 то
        for(let i =0;i < lastPosts.length;i++){
            for(let j = 0;j < newsInfo.length;j++){
                news.insertBefore(lastPosts[i], newsInfo[j]);
  //вставляем в блок news колонку lastPosts с [индексом который указывает массив] до элемента newsInfo[также индекс который указывает массив]  
            }
        }
    }
    
})
//аналогичная функцию с resize можете не посмотреть даже
window.onresize = () => {
    let w = window.innerWidth;
    let lastPosts = document.querySelectorAll(".last_posts");
    let newsInfo = document.querySelectorAll(".news_info");
    let news = document.querySelector(".news");
    let posts = document.querySelector(".posts");

    if(w <= 992){
        for(let i =0;i < lastPosts.length;i++){
            for(let j = 0;j < newsInfo.length;j++){
                news.insertBefore(lastPosts[i], newsInfo[j]);
            }
        }
    }  else if (w > 992){
        for(let i =0;i < lastPosts.length;i++){
                posts.insertBefore(lastPosts[i], null);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container no-padding">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="news col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8 col-xl-8">
      <h6 class="news_title">News</h6>
      <div class="news_info">
        <div class="statue_liberty">
          <img src="">
        </div>
        <div class="post_title">Discover Milan's religious sites</div>
        <p class="post_briefly">Canadian-born and educated Jamie Fobert has practiced architecture in England for 30 years, first under David Chipperfield and then, since 1995, as head of his own firm. During that time, he has quietly built a…</p>
        <div class="button-container-4">
          <span class="mas_">Read more  &rarr;</span>
          <button type="button" name="Hover">Read more  &rarr;</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="news_info">
        <div class="statue_liberty">
          <img src="">
        </div>
        <div class="post_title">Discover Milan's religious sites</div>
        <p class="post_briefly">Canadian-born and educated Jamie Fobert has practiced architecture in England for 30 years, first under David Chipperfield and then, since 1995, as head of his own firm. During that time, he has quietly built a…</p>
        <div class="button-container-4">
          <span class="mas_">Read more  &rarr;</span>
          <button type="button" name="Hover">Read more  &rarr;</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="news_info">
        <div class="statue_liberty">
          <img src="">
        </div>
        <div class="post_title">Discover Milan's religious sites</div>
        <p class="post_briefly">Canadian-born and educated Jamie Fobert has practiced architecture in England for 30 years, first under David Chipperfield and then, since 1995, as head of his own firm. During that time, he has quietly built a…</p>
        <div class="button-container-4">
          <span class="mas_">Read more  &rarr;</span>
          <button type="button" name="Hover">Read more  &rarr;</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="posts col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
      <div class="last_posts">
        <h3 class="last_post_title">Discover Milan's religious sites</h3>
        <p class="latest_post_briefly">Canadian-born and educated Jamie Fobert has practiced architecture in England for 30 years, first …</p>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Read</a>
      </div>
      <div class="last_posts">
        <h3 class="last_post_title">Discover Milan's religious sites</h3>
        <p class="latest_post_briefly">Canadian-born and educated Jamie Fobert has practiced architecture in England for 30 years, first …</p>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Read</a>
      </div>
      <div class="last_posts">
        <h3 class="last_post_title">Discover Milan's religious sites</h3>
        <p class="latest_post_briefly">Canadian-born and educated Jamie Fobert has practiced architecture in England for 30 years, first …</p>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Read</a>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего у тебя ошибка в логике цикла:

```
for(let i =0;i < lastPosts.length;i++){
            for(let j = 0;j < newsInfo.length;j++){
                news.insertBefore(lastPosts[i], newsInfo[j]);
            }
        }
```

у тебя  внутри вложенного цикла идет вставка одного и того же элемента сначала перед  `newsInfo[0]`, затем значение `i` у тебя не меняется и ты тот же элемент `lastPost[i]` вставляешь(перемещаешь) уже перед `newsInfo[1]` и так далее.. то есть тупо перемещается несколько раз один и тот же блок, и в конце вложенного цикла он остается перед последним `newsInfo[]`

Насколько я понял у тебя количество `lastPost` равно количеству newsInfo,
 тогда тебе, если я понял твою логику нужно использовать один цикл но это будет только при совпадении их количества, иначе еще проверки надо добавить

```
for(let i =0;i < lastPosts.length;i++){
         news.insertBefore(lastPosts[i], newsInfo[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Эммм а где ответ?

Comment: так  я ответил же  на поставленный вопрос : "Почему при цикле insertBefore добавляет все три элементы в одно место?" Потому что не выходишь из цикла где надо

Comment: нужно решить данный вопрос

Comment: чел.. программисты получают з/п за то что они  делают сами.   не у каждого есть время решать вопрос. но можно подсказать где ошибка

Comment: спасибо за помощь